# Docker: can't get latest tag on many images

Tags: centos, docker, centos7

For some reason, my installation of Docker can't run almost any images. For example, the usual `hello-world` image:

```
# docker run hello-world

Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/hello-world ... 
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/hello-world
docker: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/hello-world.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
```

Of course, [`hello-world` does have a `latest` tag](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/).

#### Why would docker be unable to find the `latest` tag?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy

Comment: curl docker.io/library/hello-world and see if it works.  It sounds like there is some kind of network issue preventing you from pulling images.

Comment: `curl docker.io/library/hello-world` returns nothing; but no error

Comment: Use `curl -v` for verbose output.

Comment: [This is what I get](http://pastebin.com/cawPjdXt)

Comment: That output looks okay?  Seems silly but have you tried restarting Docker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44971/discussion-between-martin-and-jmreicha).